# Getting issue on calculating amount on input type number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have write jquery code with use of classes,
the problem is each product gets incremented even i changed for just one product.
I want to do if user increment one field than the amount will calculat in his parent text-box, but actually when i increment for one product the amount increment for both product.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".quantity").change(function(){
        $(".subTotal").val(parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($(".price").val()));
    });
    
});

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
<tr>
 <td><input type="text"  class="price" value="1000" readonly></td>
 <td><input type="number" min="0" class="quantity" value="1"></td>
 <td><input type="text"  class="subTotal" value="1000"></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
 <td><input type="text"  class="price" value="1000" readonly></td>
 <td><input type="number" min="0" class="quantity" value="1"></td>
 <td><input type="text"  class="subTotal" value="1000"></td>
</tr>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".quantity").change(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.subTotal').val(parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('.price').val()));
    });
});

/*
BEFORE YOU EDITED THE QUESTION
$(function() {
  $(".quantity").change(function(){
    $(this).nextAll(".subTotal:first").val(parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($(this).nextAll('.price:first').val()));
    });
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
 <td><input type="text"  class="price" value="1000" readonly></td>
 <td><input type="number" min="0" class="quantity" value="1"></td>
 <td><input type="text"  class="subTotal" value="1000"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="text"  class="price" value="1000" readonly></td>
 <td><input type="number" min="0" class="quantity" value="1"></td>
 <td><input type="text"  class="subTotal" value="1000"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<!--
BEFORE YOU EDITED THE QUESTION
<input type="number" min="0" class="quantity" value="1">
<input type="text"  class="price" value="1000" readonly>
<input type="text"  class="subTotal" value="1000">

<input type="number" min="0" class="quantity" value="1">
<input type="text"  class="price" value="1000" readonly>
<input type="text"  class="subTotal" value="1000">
-->
```

Comment: @KaushalShah do you understand all, or you need any comments?

Comment: Hello sir I have checked in my script  and found that is not working. My script has table and this code is not working as aspected  between<tr><td> </td></tr> .

Comment: I need to see a bit of your html. please edit the question.

Comment: Hello I editted my script with table <tr><td> </td></tr>, Kindly check it out.

Comment: Done. Let me know.

Comment: You given me the correct solution as i wanted but i stuck on one thing. the quantity and calculate amount we are creating on javascript, is it possible that calculated amount and quantity can be updated using javascript, I mean can i fire UPDATE query in javascript to update quantity and subtotal in database, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Get input elements based on event fired element. Use **[`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)** and **[`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first)** method to get the inputs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".quantity").change(function() {
    // cache the `$(this)` jQuery object
    var $this = $(this);
    $this
      // get all siblings next to it with class `subTotal`
      .nextAll(".subTotal")
      // get the adjucent one
      // .nextAll(".subTotal").first() ==> .nextAll(".subTotal:first")
      .first()
      // updates its value
      .val(
        // multiply with adjucent pric input 
        ($this.val() * $this.nextAll(".price").first().val()) || 0
      );
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".quantity").change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.nextAll(".subTotal").first()
      .val(($this.val() * $this.nextAll(".price").first().val()) || 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" min="0" class="quantity" value="1">

<input type="text" class="price" value="1000" readonly>
<input type="text" class="subTotal" value="1000">

<input type="number" min="0" class="quantity" value="1">

<input type="text" class="price" value="1000" readonly>
<input type="text" class="subTotal" value="1000">
```

---

Or use **[`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)** method to get all elements up to the next quantity input and filter element using **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".quantity").change(function() {
    // get all elements before the next quantity field
    var $ele = $(this).nextUntil('.quantity');
    $ele
    // filter out `.subTotal` from it
      .filter(".subTotal")
      // updates its value
      .val(
        // multiply with adjucent pricr input 
        (this.value * $ele.filter(".price").val()) || 0
      );
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".quantity").change(function() {
    var $ele = $(this).nextUntil('.quantity');
    $ele.filter(".subTotal")
      .val((this.value * $ele.filter(".price").val()) || 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" min="0" class="quantity" value="1">

<input type="text" class="price" value="1000" readonly>
<input type="text" class="subTotal" value="1000">

<input type="number" min="0" class="quantity" value="1">

<input type="text" class="price" value="1000" readonly>
<input type="text" class="subTotal" value="1000">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only allowed to use classes, you might try wrapping each pair of inputs in a span, who have classes/ids going from 1 to 3. Then, in the onchange function, you can get the parent of this and loop through all the .price elements until you have the element with the same parentnode as this. Now knowing what element you want to affect, you can now easily get/set text in said element.